# What Azure Messaging Service to use?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I have a specific case that I would like to solve using an Azure Messaging Service, but I'm not sure which one to use. There are 7 to choose from and I think I have narrowed it down to 2 options.

- Azure Service Bus Topic
- Azure Event Hubs

I will try to explain my needs using the following diagram. Please bare in mind that this is just a fictional scenario, just to illustrate what I'm after.

[image]

- A user updates a Product. An HTTP request is send to an MVC application.
- The MVC applications puts a `UpdateProductCommand`on the bus (what Azure Bus?)
- Inside Azure, wether it is an Azure Function, or something else, the command must be processed.
- Inside the command handler I want to publish an Event telling all listening parties that a certain task has been processed.
- So an `ProductUpdatedEvent` gets published
- There will be more than 1 application interested in consuming this event. These apps can live inside Azure as an Azure Function. But it must also be possible for applications to consume events that are hosted on an external server. Inside my own IIS server for example.

Requirements:

- When an application/eventhandler that consumes an event goes down for x time, and later gets up again, then it should be able to process all the events it missed.
- An event can be consumed by more than one event handler. All event handlers should process the event.
- An event must be able to carry data. Like on the right in the screenshot. I want to be able to send data about the product that got updated.

Which Azure Messaging Service technology would best fit this description?

Comment: I'd say use azure service bus for the commands and event grid for the events. I was wondering why you left event grid out of the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Azure Service Bus.

Clients can be responsible for creating their own subscriptions and get their own instance of the message you send. So in the final part of your diagram the Product Microservice/Inventory Microservice would each be able to process the message at their own rate and if one went down it wouldn't affect the other, they would both be able to read their own message. It gets sent once and read twice.

You can have a look at the tiers of Service Bus to see if the cost/storage meets your needs but you should be able to store millions and millions (80Gb) of messages on the topic depending on what you put in the message. Each message can be up to 1Mb of text so your number will differ depending on what you're doing. Then the microservices comes back online it can work through the backlog.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents on this, as both can be used to achieve the same, and some architects would decide for one, the others for the other:

I believe you have read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services) which starts from the distinction between the message and the event, and the philosophy behind.

- "The publisher of the message has an expectation about how the consumer handles the message"
- "The publisher of the event has no expectation about how the event is handled"

From this, and based on your requirements, I understood that your publisher does not care how the handler will handle the event - for the publisher it does not represent the value as handlers should not send any response/confirmation. This goes more in the Event-Hub 'spirit'

Now, you said that you want to carry the data. By the definition, again from the documentation:

- "An event is a lightweight notification of a condition or a state change"
- "The message contains the data that triggered the message pipeline."

So, 'carrying a data' is more a message, than the event, as the message contains the information, and the event contains the fact that the state has changed. This goes more in the Service bus topic 'spirit' and philosophy, as the message contains high-value transactional data that should not be lost.

Another requirement, and in my opinion the most important one, says that you would like to have more than one event handler.
Now, the way to have more than one event-handler with Event-Hub is to create for each one of them a separate Consumer Group.
The way how you can have more than one event-handler with the Service-Bus topic is that you just subscribe.

So finally, my 2 cents, if you want more to have more flexibility with handlers, I would go with Service Bus topics, as you can add as many as you want subscribers(event handlers) in the runtime as you want, without any adjustment on Service Bus topic itself,

If you think that your solution will go more in the direction that you will have a finite number of handlers/consumers, and you might have concurrent event publishers, I would then choose the Event-Hub here, and I would just create for each of my handlers a Consumer group - which is not what I understood from your initial requirements.

Comment: Do mind [the limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#basic-and-standard-tiers) regarding the maximum number of consumer groups!